# jQuery datatables plugin and only deleting from the first part of a table works

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use jQuery datatables plugin.

In my table I have a column for deleting rows. I used this selector in my columns:

```
<td> <span class="icon_text accept"></span> </td>
```

And I wrote some code to delete a row from the table:

```
   $(".accept").click(function (e) {
       //Delete
   });
```

Everything works fine, but just in page one of the table. It means if my table has more than one page, the selector does not work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code to:

```
$(".accept").live('click', function(e) {
    //Delete
});
```

Comment: ممنون مجید جان :)
But I added click handler to selector before applying datatable to my table . any way thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome! Please note that live is exactly for this situation: to bind a function to events of elements not present in the dom yet! So it should work.